# Вывести данные из коллекции по массиву

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть.

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541c03489c3009e80de19d6b"),
    "ts" : 1411121993,
    "close" : false,
    "users" : [ 
        "7e8f5f8fc847bc6", 
        "920299d58dc02ec"
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541c035f9c3009e80de19d6c"),
    "ts" : 1411122016,
    "close" : false,
    "users" : [ 
        "7e8f5f8fc847bc6", 
        "a285496ba35fe98"
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541c035f9c3009e80de19d6d"),
    "ts" : 1411122016,
    "close" : false,
    "users" : [ 
        "7e8f5f8fc847bc6", 
        "c2f1f4e949237d1"
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Это коллекция диалогов.

Допустим, мой id - *7e8f5f8fc847bc6*.

Мне нужно создать новый диалог с пользователем id - *c2f1f4e949237d1*.

Для этого мне нужно проверить на существование такого диалога.

Если он уже существует и close: false, то нужно выдать его dialog id, если нет - создать новый.

Проблема в том, что я не пойму, как в mongoose сделать запрос проверки.

В массиве users данные могут быть **в любом порядке**, но их не может быть больше двух.

На языке sql это примерно вот так:

```
select ... where (users = ['c2f1f4e949237d1', '7e8f5f8fc847bc6'] or users = ['7e8f5f8fc847bc6', 'c2f1f4e949237d1']) and close = false
```

Comment: @ua6xh, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> db.dialogs.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("541c03489c3009e80de19d6b"), "ts" : 1411121993, "close" : false, "users" : [ "7e8f5f8fc847bc6", "920299d58dc02ec" ], "__v" : 0 }
>
> db.dialogs.find({users:"7e8f5f8fc847bc6", users:"920299d58dc02ec", close:false});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("541c03489c3009e80de19d6b"), "ts" : 1411121993, "close" : false, "users" : [ "7e8f5f8fc847bc6", "920299d58dc02ec" ], "__v" : 0 }
>
>
> db.dialogs.find({users:"7e8f5f8fc847bc6", users:"920299d58dc02ec", close:false},{_id:1});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("541c03489c3009e80de19d6b") }
>
```

---

Upd2:

```
db.dialogs.find(
    {$and:[
        {users:"7e8f5f8fc847bc6hghg"}, 
        {users:"920299d58dc02ec"}, 
        {close:false}
    ]},
    {_id:1}
);
```

Comment: Потрясающе! Спасибо!

Comment: @exec, я думаю, надо будет делать составной индекс по (users, close). В любом случае стоит создать около 1 млн записей и проверить выборки с индексом и без.

Comment: @ua6xh, проверю, посмотрю.
___

@ua6xh, стоп. Это поиск не точный. Он ищет либо по одному, либо по другому.
db.dialog.find({users: 'hjhj', users: '920299d58dc02ec'});
тоже найдет

Comment: @exec, обновил ответ по новым требованиям к запросу. Поиск проходит только по общему совпадению.

Comment: @ua6xh

http://src.unotes.ru/g/dxpsy.png - это нормально.  
http://src.unotes.ru/g/p6z14.png - это тоже нормально.  
http://src.unotes.ru/g/ed3ni.png - нашло, хотя не должно было.  

Может быть, у вас не находит из-за того, что один документ в коллекции?

Comment: @exec, интересный кейс, надо найти на него ответ. Да, пополнил коллекцию и тоже начал появляться этот объект, прошу извинить, был не прав.

Запрос на AND изменил:

    db.dialogs.find({$and:[{users:"7e8f5f8fc847bc6hghg"}, {users:"920299d58dc02ec"}, {close:false}]},{_id:1});